# Could not resolve view with name X in servlet with name Y

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, view

I am using Spring and AngularJS for a rest web application. Base on [this](http://www.infiniteskills.com/training/spring-mvc-for-java-developers.html) tutorial and based on [this](http://www.revillweb.com/angularjs-by-example/2-project-structure/) tutorial I've created the following folder structure:

```
-src
|----main
    |----webapp
        |----static
            |----api
            |----assets
            |----resources
            |----sections
            |----services
            |----index.html
        |----WEB-INF
            |----web.xml
            |----spring
                |----dispatcher-servlet.xml
                |----applicationContext.xml
```

I want to serve static HTML files so I declared the resources as following:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

<mvc:annotation-driven></mvc:annotation-driven>
<context:component-scan base-package="org.tools.mvc.controllers"></context:component-scan>
<mvc:resources location="/static/" mapping="/**"/>
<mvc:resources location="/static/api/" mapping="/api/**"/>
<mvc:resources location="/static/assets/" mapping="/assets/**"/>
<mvc:resources location="/static/resources/" mapping="/resources/**"/>
<mvc:resources location="/static/services/" mapping="/services/**"/>
<mvc:resources location="/static/sections/home/" mapping="/sections/home/**"/>


<bean name="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver"></bean>
<bean name="jsonTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJackson2JsonView"></bean>
```

My problem is that when I deploy the application( I am using Glassfish server) the following error occurs( in Eclipse console and also in the browser page):

```
2016-05-27T04:46:06.640-0700|Warning: StandardWrapperValve[dispatcher]: Servlet.service() for servlet dispatcher threw exception
javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name 'index.html' in servlet with name 'dispatcher'
```

The functionality of the service is not affected( using Postman to test the rest api results in success). Until now, in order to further develop the application I manually added index.html to the end of the URL(like localhost:8080/status/index.html). The source of the "/" as declared in Web Deployment Assembly is:

Source:      /src/main/webapp

Deploy Path: /

**Update**: The web.xml file is looking like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
<display-name>status</display-name>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

How can I resolve this error?

Thank you

P.S The solutions found on SO didn't applied to my scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that I've declared a view resolver ( BeanNameViewResolver) inside applicationContext.xml. After deleting the view resolver, I didn't receive the error.

The error occurred because Spring was trying to interpret my view( witch was a html static file) to a bean.